# How to list all files of specific extensions inside a folder with numbering order using batch file

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, cmd

My question is, How can I list or print name of files of specific extension ONLY inside a folder using a batch file. Extensions are .apk and .jar

Let me explain with an example, Say a folder name files has four files in it namely "framework-res.apk" "systemui.apk" "game.apk" and "7z.exe"
Now I place a bat file there, execute it and want it to return this output on screen

```
1) "framework-res.apk"

2) "systemui.apk"

3) "game.apk"
```

Bat should be able to print no matter how many files in it with .apk extension and in serial-wise like stated above (Numbered order) like if it had 3 more apk files it should automatically continue like

```
4) bla.apk 

5) wea.apk
```

and so on..

and it should not print any other file extension rather than .apk or .jar inside it, like "7z.exe"
I have trying my head around this but could not get any logic! Kindly share some ideas/method to do this. I'll be very grateful.
I tried explaining the best I could hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shortest way, if you can live with a slightly different layout:

```
dir /b *.apk|findstr /n "^"
```

Keeping your given layout, it's a bit more complicated:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a x=0
for %%i in (*.apk) do (
  set /a x +=1
  echo !x!^) "%%i"
)
```

for the input-thingy:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a x=0
(for %%i in (*.apk) do (
  set /a x +=1
  echo !x!^) "%%i"
))>dir.txt

:loop
type dir.txt
set /p "c=enter number: "
if "%c%"=="" goto :loop
if %c% gtr %x% goto :loop
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%i in ('findstr /b "%c%)" dir.txt') do set choosen=%%j
echo your file is: %choosen%
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I am such an idiot! Didn't got my mind clicked regarding this one! Thank you! But if I stick to layout how will that be possible?

Comment: You sir are a legend! :D Thank you! One more thing If I want user to enter an input (input number) like 2 or 3 how can I take the input and convert it into the filename using "set /p" command

Comment: I am very sorry for these end moment questions. I am all done now thank you sir. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

very simple 
powershell command

```
ls *.apk
```

or 
use this script can search all drive and get apk app

```
Get-PSDrive | where { $_.Provider -match "FileSystem"} | select Root | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem $_.Root -n
ame *.apk -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' }
```

Comment: in batch file you just put `powershell ls *.apk` or that script use in batch file `powershell -encodedcommmand IABHAGUAdAAtAFAAUwBEAHIAaQB2AGUAIAB8ACAAdwBoAGUAcgBlACAAewAgACQAXwAuAFAAcgBvAHYAaQBkAGUAcgAgAC0AbQBhAHQAYwBoACAAIgBGAGkAbABlAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtACIAfQAgAHwAIABzAGUAbABlAGMAdAAgAFIAbwBvAHQAIAB8ACAARgBvAHIARQBhAGMAaAAtAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAAewAgAEcAZQB0AC0AQwBoAGkAbABkAEkAdABlAG0AIAAkAF8ALgBSAG8AbwB0ACAALQBuAAoAYQBtAGUAIAAqAC4AYQBwAGsAIAAtAEUAcgByAG8AcgBBAGMAdABpAG8AbgAgACcAUwBpAGwAZQBuAHQAbAB5AEMAbwBuAHQAaQBuAHUAZQAnACAAfQAgAA==` that's encoded powershell script for use in cmd

Comment: nice. How does this help?